# Domain to Model classes

Tags: java, hibernate, architecture, dao

I am writing some code that will serve a website and I have some questions about my "architecture".

1. **Domain** I have a database and and at the lowest level I have the **Domain* *package that contains the classes that represent the tables of the database. I use Hibernate and lazy fetch for relationships.
2. **Access** This package has all the classes that perform database actions on the *domains*. I guess this is the equivalent of DAO. I get entries using the primary key, return all the entries in a table, perform a query on it. Everything is returns as a *domain* class or a collection of it.
3. **Service** This packages has the class (again related to a *domain* class each) that has more complex logic. It uses the **Access** package to get *domain* objects and transform them to *model* objects where *model* is what I call classes that represent an equivalent *domain* class but without the members that have relationships on them like *ToMany which would possibly have hibernate proxies that cannot be serialised and also make the object "heavier". In the future I might write custom methods/transformation to turn those collections of *domain* object to something descriptive for presentation but for now I disregarde them.
4. **Model** This package has the exact same number of classes as the **Domain** and like I mentioned is the a representation of the *domain* objects to something I can use for presentations, transmit, etc. (This is like parallel to the other hierarchy not part of the order.)
5. **Servlet** This packages contains all the Servlets for the websites and each servlet contains the code for something the website wants to do. It uses the *service* classes to get the data it wants to manipulate. The *service* classes will get the relevant *domain* objects and transform them to *model* objects which will be returned to the *servlet* classes that will perform the operations needed by the website request and then return to the website the data in JSON format.

So obviously I would like some feedback to this approach and my following thoughts.

1) I think the *service* classes should have only code having to do with transforming the *domain* object to a *model* object. I am thinking of using Dozer and just add code that might be needed for something more complex that Dozer can't do (basically the in the future bit). From what I saw since my *model* classes are basically *domain* classes without the heavy stuff and the members have the same name I don't even need annotations or xml.

2)In the **Access** I use as a parameter the base class of all *domain* classes so I can have an abstract class and implement all the common methods in there like so

```
public abstract class DomainAccess<T extends Domain> {

    protected abstract Logger getLogger();

    protected DatabaseFacade db;

    protected Class<T> domainClass;

    @Inject
    public DomainAccess(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, Class<T> domainClass) {
        this.db = databaseFacade;
        this.domainClass = domainClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T fetchByPrimaryKey(Object primaryKey) {
        return (T) db.find(domainClass, primaryKey);
    }

    // TODO This might be better to be used for complete comparison if expanded
    public boolean exists(T object) {
        return fetchByPrimaryKey(object.getPrimaryKey()) == null ? false : true;
    }

    public void save(T object) {
        db.save(object);
    }

    public void merge(T object) {
        db.merge(object);
    }

    public void delete(T object) {
        db.remove(object);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(T object) {
        if (exists(object)) {
            merge(object);
        } else {
            save(object);
        }
    }

    public void deleteByPrimaryKey(T object) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Object primaryKey = object.getPrimaryKey();
        T objectToDelete = fetchByPrimaryKey(primaryKey);

        if (objectToDelete == null) {
            getLogger().debug("There was no entry found with primary key: " + primaryKey);
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("No entry was found with specified primary key [" + primaryKey + "]");
        } else {
            getLogger().debug("Deleting entry with id: " + primaryKey);
            delete(objectToDelete);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> getResultList(String hql, String... parameters) {
        TypedQuery<T> query = db.createTypedQuery(hql, domainClass);
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
            query.setParameter(i + 1, parameters[i]);
        }
        return query.getResultList();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getSingleResult(String hql, String... parameters) {
        TypedQuery<T> query = db.createTypedQuery(hql, domainClass);
        for (int i = 1; i <= parameters.length; i++) {
            query.setParameter(i, parameters[i - 1]);
        }

        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

3) Similarly I think in the Service I think i shoud use the Model as a parameter like 
    public abstract class DomainService {

```
    protected abstract Logger getLogger();

    protected final Validator validator;

    protected DomainService() {
        // TODO this might be needed only for insertion so instead of a class member, maybe it's better to have it as
        // a method variable?
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        this.validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    /**
     * Inserts an entry in the database for the object passes an an argument.
     * 
     * @param object The object representing the entry to be inserted
     * @throws ValidationException When the object doesn't pass the validation. i.e. a member value is not valid based
     */
    //TODO handle validation exception with message
    abstract public void insert(T object) throws ValidationException;

    /**
     * Deletes an entry from the database. A whole object of the appropriate type is passed as an argument which
     * will be used as a storage/collection of the attributes of the entry by which the deletion can occur. Different
     * implementations can use these attributes to performs filtering and collection of entries to be deleted.
     * 
     * @param object An object representing the entry to be deleted.
     * 
     * @throws EntityNotFoundException when no entry to be deleted is found
     */
    // TODO remove TransactionRequiredException, IllegalArgumentException
    abstract public void delete(T object) throws EntityNotFoundException;

    /**
     * Returns all the entries of the table.
     * 
     * @return a list containing objects representing all the entries in the table.
     */
    abstract public List<T> fetchAll();
}
```

So, in the servlet where I will have all the values for an object I will construct a *member* instance and then pass that down to the *service* which will transform it to a *domain* or use it to update an existing *domain* object (it was retrieved form the database for instance) and so on

Comment: Your domain model is not really a domain model. They seem to be simple DTO objects, so that has nothing to do with a domain model.